Does this mean I have a failing hard drive? My server keeps shutting down
I just installed Nextcloud and all of a sudden my server keeps randomly shutting down. I've done the following:
$ sudo smartctl --quietmode=errorsonly --all /dev/sda

and here is the output:
Num  Test_Description    Status            Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error

  2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       10%      7553         3365454688

I read the logs, which led me to check the smart data. Does the above mean my HD /sda is failing? Could this be what is causing the server to keep crashing?

You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details, so we cannot currently answer your question.  An OS requires a command to shutdown, and SMART does not generally issue that command unless you've set it up to do that; have you??   If you're using an enterprise grade server, your machine logs will tell you why.. by hardware logs; boot firmware settings to view will say why; which maybe PSU issues, heat etc  however if the hardware logs say "software" caused shutdown, then it was an OS issued order & you need to look in your Ubuntu system logs for clues.

Server is running 22.04 and I'm getting the following messages in /var/log: E: Sub-process nm-online returned an error code (1) and Failed to post KMS update: drmModeAtomicCommit: Invalid argument. I don't know what these mean I'm a linux hobbyest not and IT pro. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I just found this now too: blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 2560 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0

I've been watching webmin and temps are good, usage is low. Nothing out of the ordinary.

Since smartctl says "Completed: read failure", it's safe to assume your disk is not healthy.
Replace the failing disk.

Solved...I had accidentally installed something that was causing the crash.

This answer does not help anyone. Either provide the details that will allow others not to make the same mistakes, or delete the question.
